# Airflow: Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0', 8080)

Tags: linux, gunicorn, apache-airflow

I am trying to do some stuff with Airflow.I have installed it with pip(latter in a virtual) but problem is when I want to start webserver.

```
airflow webserver -p 8080
[2017-07-29 12:20:45,913] [4585] {models.py:167} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/milenko/airflow/dags
Running the Gunicorn Server with:
Workers: 4 sync
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
Timeout: 120
Logfiles: - -
=================================================================            
[2017-07-29 12:20:46,950] {__init__.py:57} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2017-07-29 12:20:47 +0200] [4590] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
[2017-07-29 12:20:47 +0200] [4590] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8080)
[2017-07-29 12:20:47 +0200] [4590] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2017-07-29 12:20:48 +0200] [4590] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8080)
[2017-07-29 12:20:48 +0200] [4590] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2017-07-29 12:20:49 +0200] [4590] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8080)
[2017-07-29 12:20:49 +0200] [4590] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2017-07-29 12:20:50 +0200] [4590] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8080)
[2017-07-29 12:20:50 +0200] [4590] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2017-07-29 12:20:51 +0200] [4590] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8080)
[2017-07-29 12:20:51 +0200] [4590] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2017-07-29 12:20:52 +0200] [4590] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0', 8080)
```

With netstat I got this output

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1637/java
```

How to solve this?I have read somewhere that Gunicorn Server is not suited for 8080 port but all Airflow tutorials point it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either stop the Java application that uses port 8080 already or change the port for Airflow.

Not *suitable for port 8080* is pretty vague and it shouldn't matter at all, but you might have to change the connection settings on the client side too.

Comment: Change to which port?

Comment: Just pick a free one. I don't know which ports are already in use on your machine. But you can get an overview as `root` with `netstat` or test it directly with `lsof -i:8081` e.g.